# Do we still use IPersistComponentSettings in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I'm still getting to grips with WPF: can anyone tell me if we should still use [IPersistComponentSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.ipersistcomponentsettings.aspx) with WPF and if not, what is the new mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the book *Programming WPF*:

> The preferred setting mechanism for WPF applications is the one provided by .NET and VS: the [ApplicationSettingBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.aspx) class from the System.Configuration namespace with the built-in designer.

There is an example of inheriting your own settings class from *ApplicationSettingBase* provided in that link. You can also check out other ideas for saving settings, demonstrated in similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246849/best-practices-for-storing-ui-settings) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396229/wpf-c-where-should-i-be-saving-user-preferences-files).